# Set depending attribute in nested model when added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My model `Form` has nested objects: `form_fields`. FormField has an attribute named `sorting` which should be unique for a form.

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :form_fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :form_fields, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  def max_form_field_sorting
    # find and return max value of sorting in nested attributes
  end
end

class FormField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  validates_numericality_of :sorting, allow_blank: true, only_integer: true, greater_than: 0
  validates :sorting, allow_blank: true, uniqueness: {scope: :form}
end
```

I want to set the `sorting` value for new FormField whenever it was attached to a form. It should get the current maximum value for sorting from method `max_form_field_sorting` (works already) and set the sorting of new FormField to that value +1.
The problem is that there are multiple ways to attach new nested objects, sometimes the FormField is created before attaching to a Form.

```
form_field_1 = FormField.new
my_form.form_fields << form_field_1
my_form.form_fields.push(FormField.new)
my_form.form_fields = [my_form_1, my_form_2]
FormField.new(form: my_form)
Form.new(form_fields_attributes: {...})
```

What is the best practice to implement that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, we will set the sorting base on max sorting of `Form` before a `FormField` will be saved:

```
class FormField < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your current code
  before_save :set_sorting
  def set_sorting
    self.sorting ||= self.class.where(form_id: form_id).maximum(:sorting).to_i + 1
  end
end
```

So we only set `sorting` if it wasn't specified.